# Wordpress submit_button() not showing in custom plugin settings page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, submit

I have a very small custom plugin that all of a sudden is not displaying the 'Save Changes' button at the bottom of the settings page being added via add_options_page function.

The rest of the form is there, and the button shows locally but for some reason it is not showing up on the live site (v4.1.1).  I have tried removing the `submit_button()` function and adding the line below instead but no joy.

Also, I don't have any check thats says only certain users can see the button.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Changes">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see the HTML for the settings page?

Comment: It turns out, it was a SoapClient issue.  We're using it for a custom function and it wasn't enabled on the server, breaking the page.